# Construction of (general class of) function(s), which sieves out primes, w.r.t. given conditions:

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the function $F(x)$ defined in following manner:

$F(n)$ is finite (likely $F(x)\in[0,1]$) if $n$ is prime and zero otherwise:

It has to satisfy following conditions:

> (1) $F(x)$ is analytic on $x\in [m,\infty] $ for some positive $m$
>
> (and it is non decreasing at prime values )(optional condition)
>
> (2)$$\lim_{y→∞}|F(x ± iy)|e^{−2πy }= 0$$ 
>   uniformly in $x (\geqslant m)$ on every finite interval
>
> (3)$$\int_0^\infty |F(x + iy) − F(x − iy)|e^{−2πy} dy$$
>   exists for every $x ≥ m$ and tends to zero when $x → ∞$

I've got a function almost satisfying above conditions:

$$F(x)= \sin^2(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x})$$

The above function satisfies condition (1) and (2) but doesn't seem to satisfy the 3rd condition .

> > Question : How to construct a function that satisfies all above conditions?

Comment: Could you write a more specific title? *"satisfying the following conditions"* is not very useful in a title. Could you start with specifying the domain and range of the function? be more precise that "$F(n)$ is finite"? etc. Currently this looks pretty unclear.

Comment: @YCor thank you for the comment , I've edited the question to my best ability . Considering the generality of the question providing domain and range will restrict the problem hugely ; So, I kept it that way .( Also forgive me : my English is not good)

Comment: could you remove spacings before punctuation marks? this is wrong typography.

Comment: @YCor thank you for the correction , I've edited it.